# Firebase Cloud Function in Typescript integration with Flutter not Working after appcheck

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I am not able to pass document from firebase cloud function to flutter app.

So I am trying to perform a basic GET operation using a Firebase cloud function.
If I check the log then, cloud function is getting triggered.

```
export const onGetNewQuestion = functions.https // }) //   enforceAppCheck: true, // .runWith({
  .onCall((data, context) => {
    
    console.log('Inside onGetNewQuestion');

    const MAX_QUESTIONS = 2;

    var db = admin.firestore();
    var questions = db.collection('questions');

    //fetching random number from database
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_QUESTIONS);
    console.log('Random number: ', random);

    //Select random question from database
    questions
      .where('id', '>=', random)
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        return {
          code: 200,
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Question fetched successfully',
          data: querySnapshot.docs[0].data(),
        };
      });
  });
```

Now the response is captured in Flutter.

```
Future<Question> getQuestion() async {
    try {
      HttpsCallable callable =
          FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('onGetNewQuestion');
      final result = await callable({
        'mytext': 'A message sent from a client device',
      });

      if (result.data != null) {
        QuestionModel question = QuestionModel.fromJson(result.data);
        return question;
      }
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      log.e(error.code);
      log.e(error.details);
      log.e(error.message);
    } catch (error) {
      log.e(error.toString());
    }
```

Here Exception is getting triggered

```
error.code = unavailable
error.details = null
error.message = unavailable
```

```
2023-06-13 00:59:18.160 IST
onGetNewQuestion2jwfegrf8z5q Inside onGetNewQuestion
2023-06-13 00:59:18.164 IST
onGetNewQuestion2jwfegrf8z5q Random number: 1
2023-06-13 00:59:18.173 IST
onGetNewQuestion2jwfegrf8z5q Function execution took 187 ms, finished with status code: 200
2023-06-13 01:00:54.029 IST
onGetNewQuestion2jwfegrf8z5q Snapshot: { description: 'So Cute!', emoji: 'u1f609', id: 1 }
```

Now, my cloud function is getting triggered but there is no return value.
Plus Snapshot is getting printed despite any console.log() function.

Pls help? Is it some deployment issue? as I have deployed it many times, but Snapshot is always showing in the end.
It was working a while back, could it be due to app check, As I activated it but there were too many issues so I stop its enforcement from firebase website.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );

  const bool USE_EMULATOR = false;

  if (USE_EMULATOR) {
    // [Firestore | localhost:8080]
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);

    FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```